# DomPdf перестал работать после переноса на другой сервер

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Имеется следующий сайт - http://michigan.selfit.org/team-profiles/?division=2
При клике на любую из школ формируется PDF документ с определенной статистикой и выводиться в новую вкладку.

Код формирования приведен ниже:

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "./dompdf"); // path to DomPDF 
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"; // config in folder DomPDF

@$id = $_GET[schoolid];
@$division = $_GET[div];

    global $wpdb;
    $first=date('Y');
    $next=date('Y')-1; 
    $year= $next.'-'.$first;

    if (!empty($id)) {

        $scl = $michigan_af->get_schools_id($id);
        $bd = $michigan_af->get_team_result();
        $school = $michigan_af->get_schools();
        $event_id = $michigan_af->get_event_id_school($id);
        $count_bd = 0;
        $count_school = 0;
        $event_show = array();


        for ($i = 0; $i < count($bd); $i++) {
            if ($bd[$i]->division_id == $division) {
                $school_id[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->school_id;
                $r1[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->round_one;
                $r2[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->round_two;
                $r3[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->round_three;
                $total[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->total;
                $event[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->event_id;
                $date[$count_bd] = $bd[$i]->date;
                $count_bd++;
            }
        }

        $name=str_replace(" ","_",$scl->school_name);
        $school_logo=str_replace("http://michigan.selfit.org", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"],$scl->image);

        $get_team_result_for_pdf=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT `wp_team_results`.*,`wp_events`.`event_name` FROM `wp_team_results`,`wp_events` WHERE `wp_team_results`.`event_id`=`wp_events`.`id`  and `wp_team_results`.`school_id` = {$id} AND `wp_team_results`.`season` = '{$year}' AND `wp_team_results`.`division_id` = (select `id` from `wp_divisions` where `division_name` =(select `division` from `wp_schools` where `id`={$id})) AND `wp_team_results`.`currentstatus` = 0 AND `wp_team_results`.`status` LIKE 'y'");
        foreach ($get_team_result_for_pdf as $key => $value) {
            array_push( $event_show, '<tr><td>'.date('M-d-Y' ,strtotime($value->date)).'</td><td>'.$value->event_name.'</td><td>Division '.$value->division_id.'</td><td>'.$value->round_one.'</td><td>'.$value->round_two.'</td><td>'.$value->round_three.'</td><td>'.$value->total.'</td></tr><br>');
        }

        $html = '
        <div style="height: 90px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; position: absolute; font-family:helvetica,sans serif;">
            <div style="width: 20%; height: 90px;">
                <img src="'.$school_logo.'" style ="height:85px; width:90px" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 80%; margin-left: 20%; height: 90px; position: absolute; ">
                <span><b>'.$scl->school_name.'</b></span><br>
                <span>'.$scl->school_address.'</span><br>
                <span>'.$scl->contact_number.'</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 90px; border: 1px solid grey; font-family:helvetica,sans serif;">
            <table style="width: 100%; position: absolute; position: relative;">
                <tr><td>School web site:</td><td><a href="'.$scl->school_website.'">'.$scl->school_website.'</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Team web site: </td><td><a href="'.$scl->team_website.'">'.$scl->team_website.'</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Colors: </td><td>'.$scl->colors.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Conference: </td><td>'.$scl->conference.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Class: </td><td>'.$scl->class.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Enrollment: </td><td>'.$scl->enrollnment.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Division: </td><td>'.$scl->division.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Region: </td><td>'.$scl->region.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>District:</td><td>'.$scl->district.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Head Coach: </td><td>'.$scl->head_coach.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Assistant Coaches: </td><td>'.$scl->assistant_coaches.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Team Accomplishments: </td><td>'.$scl->team_accomplishments.'</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Other: </td><td>'.$scl->other.'</td></tr>
                     <!-- Events -->
            </table>
            <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;">
                <tr><td>Date</td><td>Event</td><td>Division</td><td>Round 1</td><td>Round 2</td><td>Round 3</td><td>Total</td></tr>
                '.implode($event_show).'
            </table>
        </div>';

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $paper_size = array(0,0,800, 800); // page size - point per inch, maybe 
        $dompdf->set_paper($paper_size);
        $dompdf->load_html($html); // html code       
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream($name.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));  
    }    
?>
```

После переноса данного сайта на другой сервер

Что могло пойти не так? Уже около месяца ищу ответ на данный вопрос. Гугл не помог. Посоветуйте пожалуйста возможные варианты.
P.S. использую DomPdf 0.6. конфигурации серверов выводит на закладке "links"

При выполнении скрипта ошибки отсутствуют. Лог также не содержит ошибок и предупреждений

Comment: Смотрите лог ошибок сервера или сделайте вывод всех ошибок на экран при выполнении скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте версию РНР на сайте. Возможно библиотека не хочет работать с ней.

Вам было бы проще работать с mPDF. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454521/dompdf-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-pdf-1-3-1-0-obj-type-catalog-outlines-2-0-r-pages-3-0-r/454540#454540) описан минимальный принцип работы с библиотекой.
И проверьте подключены ли все классы, которые нужны для работы.