# DomPdf выводит %PDF-1.3 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >>

Tags: php, dompdf

При формировании PDF документа при помощи DomPdf 0.6.0 в браузер вместо документа выводит - http://www.michigancompetitivecheer.com/team-profiles/?schoolid=77

`header('Content-Type: application/pdf');` не помог

`setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` не помог

Никаких ошибок на экран и в лог не выводит.

Посоветуйте, что еще можно попробовать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить к заголовку

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

еще один

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="имя_файла.pdf"');
```

Comment: Добавление второго заголовка, к сожалению, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я вот использую библиотеку [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php).
Никаких трудностей с ней не было. Отлично считывает HTML & CSS.
Прекрасный инструмент для генерации PDF документов. Вот небольшой пример кода

```
include("mpdf.php");

$html = "<h2>Hello World!</h2>";

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

А вот Вашей проблеме может помочь, по-моему только `Content-type` в `header`'e

Comment: перед выводом документа на экран заголовок передается:
`$dompdf->render();
     header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name.".pdf"');
     $dompdf->stream($name.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));`
Но это не помогает
mpdf подключу и отпишусь насчет результатов

Comment: А Вы пробовали использовать библиотеку, которую я Вам предоставил?

Comment: Я попробую и отпишусь

Comment: @Анна Куприна, если будут проблемы с адаптацией - обращайтесь

Comment: @Анна Куприна, кстати, у Вас версии PHP одинаковы на обеих серверах?

Comment: версия PHP - 5.3 на обоих серверах

Comment: @Анна Куприна, Вы уже пробовали адаптировать библиотеку mPDF? Если да, то получилось ли?

Comment: Подключила, результат аналогичный - http://www.michigancompetitivecheer.com/team-profiles/?schoolid=133

Comment: @Анна Куприна покажите пожалуйста код, который Вы используете, желательно в каком-то фидле по типу codepen или jsfiddle

Comment: я решила для начала протестировать ваш пример.

Фидл для PHP нашла следующий - http://phpfiddle.org/

Но там надо регистрироваться, поэтому размещу код сдесь
`<?php

@$id = $_GET[schoolid];

if (!empty($id)) {      
 include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
 $html = "<h2>Hello World!</h2>";
 $mpdf = new mPDF();
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $mpdf->Output();
}
     
?>
`

Comment: @Анна Куприна, я использовал данную библиотеку(mPDF) для генерации отчетов - что призводило всегда к успеху

Comment: @Анна Куприна, Вам бы желательно генерирование таких документов сделать в отдельном файле

Comment: _я использовал данную библиотеку(mPDF) для генерации отчетов - что призводило всегда к успеху_  в данном случае нет, тут уже не ясно в библиотеке ли дело, так как было протестировано несколько библиотек и html2pdf и tcpdf и dompdf, результат один и тот же

Результат лишь в том, что в dompdf данные выводятся хотя-бы не на самой странице сайта

Comment: _Вам бы желательно генерирование таких документов сделать в отдельном файле_  В смысле всю генерацию вынести в отдельный документ и вызывать в необходимом скрипте?

Comment: @Анна Куприна, вот я только что протестировал библиотеку на локальном хостинге. У меня всё работает. Даже с вышепредставленным примером. Именно так. Сделать документ generateReport.php и там уже проделывать операции с БД и библиотекой

Comment: @Анна Куприна, У меня вот был самописный класс, который я использовал для генерирования документов формата PDF. Там у меня были и отчеты по менеджерам отдельно, и за день, и за неделю, месяц и т.д. И когда мне надо было что-то сгенерировать, я `POST` (или `GET`) запросом отправлял на скрипт-обработчик нужные данные, которые надо было обработать. Такой метод генерации документа меня вполне устроил.

Comment: спасибо за совет, я попробую использовать данный подход

Comment: @Анна Куприна, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29719/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-kozin-dompdf--pdf-1-3-1-0-obj-type-ca).